# How to path set in Ubuntu 15.04 of Java , download the version of java-8-oracle?

Tags: java, 15.04, environment-variables, jdk, paths

I am new to Ubuntu. Recently we changed my OS to Ubuntu 15.04. I am  installed `java-7-openjdk-i386` from "Ubuntu Software Center" and when I use the "Android Studio" then it highly recommended me to use JDK1.7 or JDK1.8.  After that I download the JDK1.8  "java-8-oracle"  and set the path is as like that in `$ gedit ~/.bsharc`
and I write that line to set the path:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I think he forgot to refresh the ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4):

Install the JDK with a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And after that

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Check the installation:

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Later you can change the default Java with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe You forgot to refresh the ~/.bashrc please try this : 
`. ~/.bashrc`.

I downloaded the jar, and follow the same way like you did. and it works.
to check pls try java -version.